# Deserializing a json which contains @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY) and custom object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a custom object :

```
public class Response
{
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<Value> values;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    public static class Value {

        public Value(long timestamp, float val)
        {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            this.val = val;
        }
    }
}
```

But when this is being parsed, I get "Can not deserialize instance of Response$Value out of START_ARRAY token".
The json is :

```
{
"values":[[1552215648,18]]
}
```

Any idea if I'm missing something here? Or should I have a custom deserializer to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonFormat` does the trick but you also need to declare constructor with `JsonCreator` annotation. Take a look on below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response myPojo = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Response.class);
        System.out.println(myPojo);
    }
}

class Response {

    private List<Value> values;

    public List<Value> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Value> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response{" +
                "values=" + values +
                '}';
    }
}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
class Value {

    private long timestamp;
    private float val;

    @JsonCreator
    public Value(@JsonProperty("timestamp") long timestamp, @JsonProperty("val") float val) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public float getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
                "timestamp=" + timestamp +
                ", val=" + val +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code for below `JSON` payload:

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      1552215648,
      18
    ],
    [
      123,
      12.24
    ]
  ]
}
```

Prints:

```
Response{values=[Value{timestamp=1552215648, val=18.0}, Value{timestamp=123, val=12.24}]}
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. That seemed to do the trick. Also, turns out I was using the objectmapper of jackson.map and not jackson.databind. That was also throwing an unnecessary error.

Answer (score 0):

You should `JsonFormat` over the variable `values`. Also since you are having the variable as of type `List`, you need not add `JsonFormat`.

```
public class Response
    {
        @JsonProperty("values")
        @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
        private List<Value> values;

        public static class Value {
            private long timestamp;
            private float val;

            // Getters and Setters

            public Value(long timestamp, float val)
            {
                this.timestamp = timestamp;
                this.val = val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Your JSON input format would be:

```
{
  values: [
     {
       "timestamp": 589988,
       "val": 56.0,
      }
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps !! I haven't tested the code, so please ignore syntax issues if any.

Comment: Ah, the JsonFormat over the variable values doesn't help as well. :/
The variable is a list of list, right? So for the inner list, I would need JsonFormat.

Comment: No the input format will be different. WIll add that to the answer

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don&#39;t have control over the response. It is an array of long and float. Not a map. The array will be like [[1573820208,45.5]]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but since I dealt with the same problem (deserializing part of Prometheus REST API response?), and provided answers weren't helping, I would like to share my solution which should work for every similar case.

Apart from `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` it was necessary for me to add also `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation to reflect the order in which values appear in the array. I also needed `@JsonCreator` annotation on constructor and `@JsonProperty` before every constructor's argument. Using your class as an example it should look like this:

```
public class Response
    {
        private List<Value> values;

        @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
        @JsonPropertyOrder({"timestamp", "val"})
        public static class Value {
            private long timestamp;
            private float val;

            @JsonCreator
            public Value(@JsonProperty("timestamp") long timestamp,
                         @JsonProperty("val") float val)
            {
                this.timestamp = timestamp;
                this.val = val;
            }

            // Getters and Setters

        }
    }
```

Only after I used this particular set of annotations my response was deserialised without any errors.

Hope this is gonna help someone! ;)

EDIT: One note: in Prometheus response I got, an array of values of different types was called `value` and not `values`, hence it might be necessary to add a `@JsonProperty("value")` on `private List<Value> values;` field or change it's name to `value` if that is the case for anyone ;)

```
@JsonProperty("value")
private List<Value> values;
```